# How to get a permission from a relationship using CanCanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

In my app I have a model called User that has_one Talent.

In CanCanCan I have this ability:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)

  if user.nil? 
    can :read, User
    can :read, Talent, is_public?: true
  else
    can :read, Talent, is_public?: true
  end
```

My page is being rendered by the ProfilesController#show. Like this:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_ability, except: [:show]
  def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :read, @user
    authorize! :read, @user.talent

    if current_user
      sent_connections = current_user.sent_connections
      connections  = sent_connections + current_user.all_connections
      @is_connected = !(connections.select { |c| c.user.id == @user.id }.empty?)
    end
    @top_5_photos = @user.top_5_photos
  end
```

Well. Im trying to render a profile that the method: is_public returns false. But the page is being rendered correctly, while I expected was that the user cant see the page because of the rule:

```
   can :read, Talent, is_public?: true
```

What Im missing here?

Comment: What is the value of `@user.talent.is_public?`. Is it `false`?

Comment: Yes. Even I putting a cannot :read, Talent. It doesnt work. Looks like something is overriding the permissions, but I triple-checked and nothing is setting the permissions on Talents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember it correctly,

```
can :read, Talent, is_public?: true
```

^ `is_public?` above is expected to be an **attribute** by Cancancan.

But because `is_public?` is a custom method, then can you try the following instead?

```
can :read, Talent do |talent|
  talent.is_public?
end
```

Comment: It works with methods too Jay. I know because on my other side of the IF, the declaration is working perfectly :/ 

Anyway, I tried with this setting too and didnt works

Comment: even putting a cannot :read, Talent , on the "else", the page is shown :/

Comment: Hmm. Can you try adding `cannot :manage, :all` at the very end of your ability.rb's `initialize` method? Because this will override everything to be "not-authorised!". Then try again and you should hopefully not be able to see the page

Comment: @FernandoMaymone, I just looked at it right now from the official docs, that you are supposed to just only use attributes there, and you should not use custom methods (but will still probably work, from my what I could remember, and is why yours still work; however I remember having some problems before with this, and was why I had to use the "block" form). See [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities#hash-of-conditions): I quote: "It is important to only use database columns for these conditions so it can be used for Fetching Records."

Comment: I did a desperate test here. And still is showing the page: 

    if user.nil? 
      can :read, User
      can :read, Talent, is_public?: true
    else
      can :read, Talent do |talent|
        false
      end
    end

Comment: If `cannot :manage, :all` still allowed the rendering of the page, then maybe your "initialize" method was not actually being called, or that your `show` action is not getting called, or that for some reason you have a different `ability` object defined/overidding `current_ability` method somewhere, maybe in your application_controller

Comment: If I add a simple  cannot :read, Talent , it works. But if I try to do a can :read, Talent do |talent|
  talent.is_public?
end

It doesnt. Even If instead of talent.is_public? I put a false.

Comment: hmm i see. I want to check something, can you try `can :read, Talent do |talent|; puts 'XXXXXXX'; puts talent.is_public?; end`. And then look at the running `rails server`, it should print out the value. Can you let me know the value being displayed? If it's false or true?

Comment: I putted too a byebug inside. And it didnt print the puts 'XXXXX'. But before and after the Talent do |talent|, it prints any puts. ?????

Comment: puts "*** Out"
      can :read, Talent do |talent|
        puts "*** In"
        puts talent.is_public?
        puts "*** In"
      end
      puts "*** Out"

Only the OUTS are printed

Comment: @FernandoMaymone hmm it is looking to me like the `show` method is not being called. So, can you try adding `puts 'MMMMMMMM'` just above `authorize! :read, @user.talent` in your `show` method? and let me know if "MMMMM" gets printed out

Comment: weirdest thing. If I put a cannot :Talent do |talent|, the "INS" are printed correctly :/

Comment: Hmm ok, I want to filter out if the `current_ability` got overriden, so can you try instead of `authorize! :read, @user.talent`, replace that with `Ability.new(current_user).authorize! :read, @user.talent`?

Comment: Another question, can you also check if `@user.talent` in fact is not `nil`? like maybe: `puts '>>>>>> @user.talent = ', @user.talent`

Comment: I found this in the code: 

 can :read, :all

Probably this option overrides all right?

Comment: ^ depends on where you put that. Because the `Ability` class implements linearly, meaning, if you put `can :read, :all` at the very end of `def initialize`, then yes that will override everything to be "authorised" on `:read`

Comment: Did you have `can :read, :all` there??? Then if so, then that was the cause of your problem!! XD

Comment: Yes Jay. I was giving maintanence in a very old code, and it was very well hidden btw a lot of comments. Sorry for missing our time. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: @FernandoMaymone No prob at all! :)) Glad I helped you in some way!